# how to get file name from URI

Tags: android, media-player

Hello
I am develop video player with android gallery.
I receive URI from gallry. and I need to display video title, when play video.
so if content has not title meta data. I need to disaplay video file name.
How to get video content file name?

thank you

Comment: So you want to display the URI? Or split it by / and display the last part?

Comment: I want to display last part. if I display URI vALUE is /external/video/media/3. but 3 is id. not file name.

Comment: Look at this other post:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105593/get-file-name-from-uri-string-in-c-sharp][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105593/get-file-name-from-uri-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: Google's answer: 
https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info.html

Answer (score 28):

Here is the code for getting name of file from url

```
Uri u = Uri.parse("www.google.com/images/image.jpg");

File f = new File("" + u);

f.getName();
```

Comment: Not working in my case it only gives the name at the end of the url but while fetching the documents from the files inside of the Google drive or somewhere else it returns the string after the last forward slash.

Answer (score 10):

Since none of the answers really solve the questions, i put my solution here, hope it will be helpful.

```
     String fileName;
     if (uri.getScheme().equals("file")) {
            fileName = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        } else {
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{
                        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME
                }, null, null, null);

                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    fileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    Log.d(TAG, "name is " + fileName);
                }
            } finally {

                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

If the uri is a content provider uri, this is how you should retrieve file info.

```
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        /*
         * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
         * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
         * and display it.
         */
        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        nameView.setText(cursor.getString(nameIndex));
```

https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info.html

Comment: How in the world is this the API? It looks like we're trying to reverse engineer some object.

Answer (score 4):

For kotlin just simply:

```
val fileName = File(uri.path).name
```

Comment: Is that really Kotlin specific? I think this also works with the corresponding Java-Syntax, right? I also think, that there are some side conditions regarding the "nature" of the uri. But anyway, for me this was the simplest solution.

Answer (score 2):

Below code works for me in case of image from gallery, It should work for any file type.

```
    String fileName = "default_file_name";
    Cursor returnCursor =
            getContentResolver().query(YourFileUri, null, null, null, null);
    try {
        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst(); 
        fileName = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex);
        LOG.debug(TAG, "file name : " + fileName);
    }catch (Exception e){
        LOG.error(TAG, "error: ", e);
        //handle the failure cases here
    } finally {
        returnCursor.close();
    }
```

[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info.html) you can find detailed explanation and much more.

Answer (score 1):

```
int actual_image_column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); 
String filename = cursor.getString(actual_image_column_index);
```

This is example for Image . you can try same thing for your needs ( video).

Thanks & Best Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

```
try
        {
            String uriString = "http://somesite.com/video.mp4";
            URI uri = new URI(uriString);

            URL videoUrl = uri.toURL();
            File tempFile = new File(videoUrl.getFile());
            String fileName = tempFile.getName();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Someone downvoted  the answer. Could you, please, explain why?

Comment: @Grsmto, sorry, but did you even try to run the code before writing your comment? I think no, because I just checked your example url and it returned proper result - file.mp3

Comment: I may be wrong, realised my Android Studio debugger is acting really weirdly...got some old cache of previous builds and all...I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Google reference:**

https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info#RetrieveFileInfo

```
        /*
         * Get the file's content URI from the incoming Intent,
         * then query the server app to get the file's display name
         * and size.
         */
        Uri returnUri = returnIntent.getData();
        Cursor returnCursor =
                getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);
        /*
         * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
         * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
         * and display it.
         */
        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
        TextView nameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.filename_text);
        TextView sizeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.filesize_text);
        nameView.setText(returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
        sizeView.setText(Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code,

```
    public String getFileName(Uri uri) {
        String result = null;
        if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            try {
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        if (result == null) {
            result = uri.getPath();
            int cut = result.lastIndexOf('/');
            if (cut != -1) {
                result = result.substring(cut + 1);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Here i am giving you a sample code which will upload image from gallery

To extract `filename/Imagename`,Do the following

```
File f = new File(selectedPath);
System.out.println("Image name is   ::" + f.getName());//get name of file

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
switch (requestCode) {
case 1:
if (resultCode == YourActivity.RESULT_OK) {
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
String selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
File f = new File(selectedPath);
System.out.println("Image name is   ::" + f.getName());//get name of file
}
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: `getPath()` is a custom function, that is not listed in your code snippet