# getting image name of image selected from gallery in android

Tags: android, image, gallery

I have browsed image from gallery and set it to `ImageView` now I need to get image name of image that have been set in `ImageView`. I have attached my code below.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("req","req"+requestCode);
    Log.d("res","res"+resultCode);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);

        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView1);

        if(browse == 1){
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }
        if(browse == 2){
            imageView1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }
        String resName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.id.imgView);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BBB"+resName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this        [how to get file name from URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263002/how-to-get-file-name-from-uri)

```
File f = new File(picturePath);
String imageName = f.getName();
```

Comment: thank u getting file name ...how to compare two file..but picture path is same

Comment: use this function f.compareTo(file2);

Comment: camparing f1.compareTo(f2); i am get value 0

Comment: if value 0 then both file are same . Refer this url http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Comparable.html

Answer (score 3):

As per [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info#java):

```
    /*
     * Get the file's content URI from the incoming Intent,
     * then query the server app to get the file's display name
     * and size.
     */
    Uri returnUri = returnIntent.getData();
    Cursor returnCursor =
            getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);
    /*
     * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
     * and display it.
     */
    int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
    returnCursor.moveToFirst();
    TextView nameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.filename_text);
    TextView sizeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.filesize_text);
    nameView.setText(returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
    sizeView.setText(Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));
```