# Get the name of image

Tags: android

i'm using this code :

Image selector

```
select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"),REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
```

Display image in imageview :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_CODE && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data !=null && data.getData() != null)
    {
        Uri uri=data.getData();
        try{
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),uri);

            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But i want to get the name of the image selected, to send it to another activity, how can i do that please ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23777347/2950010

Answer (score 0):

**MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA**
will return real path of image, have look this

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_CODE && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data !=null && data.getData() != null)
    {
        Uri uri=data.getData();
        String s = getRealPathFromURI(uri);
        try{
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),uri);

            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: When i transfer it to another activity, nothing show