# No image extension when sharing using an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-resources

I use the following code in order to share an image :

```
 Uri imguri=Uri.parse("android.resource://PackageName/drawable/"+ R.drawable.img);
 Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 intent.setType("image/png");
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imguri);
 Intent ch=Intent.createChooser(intent,"Send image");
 startActivity(ch);
```

The file is sent (for instance using GMAIL) but the problem is that there is no extension. It is simply named 2130837559.

Is there a way to get the real name (img) and the extension (png) ?

Comment: Please check this answer for getting name: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4263552/1773155

Comment: And to get extension you can do: `filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf("."));`

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal: Neither you nor the OP are the authors of Gmail. Your code is at best relevant for the *recipient* of a `Uri` to pick out those values. The OP is the *sender* of the `Uri`. Moreover, his `Uri` does not have a filename or a file extension.

Answer (score 2):

Partly, that is up to the email client, not you.

Partly, that is because your code does not send the real name or the extension. `R.drawable.img` is an `int`, quite possibly `2130837559` in decimal. If you look at your `Uri` that you are sending, you will not see the filename or the file extension.

Your only hope for getting Gmail to think in terms of your filename and extension will be to have a `Uri` that has those values in it. Solutions include:

- Copying the resource to a file on [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) and using a `file://` `Uri` (not recommended)
- Copying the resource to a file on [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) and [using `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to give you a `content://` `Uri`
- Using [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) to serve the value straight out of raw resources, and setting up the `name` to give your resulting `Uri` a filename and extension (note: this would require you to have the PNG file as a raw resource, rather than as a drawable resource)

Comment: Thank you @CommonWare but what's the best option ? (a sample code would be greatly appreciated).

Comment: @WildThing: The best middle-ground option (solid yet not a big pain to implement) would be the `FileProvider` one. [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) demonstrates the technique. The differences are that I am copying a PDF from assets and using `ACTION_VIEW`. I am also blending in [my `LegacyCompatCursorWrapper`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider#usage-legacycompatcursorwrapper) to improve compatibility with various older apps.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to change the "R.drawable.img"
in your "imguri" to "getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.img)".