# Getting file name in integer format

Tags: android

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
        Log.e("filepath",String.valueOf(FilePath));
        String FileName = data.getData().getLastPathSegment();

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, FilePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0,
                        0);
    }
}
```

I need to get file name as `/video.mp4` but am getting `/35370`

am getting like this E/filepath: /external/video/media/35424
but i want like this E/filepath: /external/video/media/video.mp4

Please give me some proper suggestions I have done all the changes by seeing other posts

Logcat:

```
10-13 12:25:34.818 15662-15662/com.onnurinet.andriodstb D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
10-13 12:25:40.366 15662-15662/com.onnurinet.andriodstb E/filepath: /external/video/media/35370
10-13 12:25:40.379 15662-15662/com.onnurinet.andriodstb D/string: 35370
10-13 12:25:40.721 15662-15662/com.onnurinet.andriodstb D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.onnurinet.andriodstb-2/libvlcjni.so 0x4190f130
10-13 12:25:40.722 15662-15662/com.onnurinet.andriodstb W/linker: libvlcjni.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
10-13 12:25:40.740 15662-15662/com.onnurinet.andriodstb D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.onnurinet.andriodstb-2/libvlcjni.so 0x4190f130
10-13 12:25:40.740 15662-15662/com.onnurinet.andriodstb D/VLC/JNI/main: JNI interface loaded.
```

Comment: whats the OS version you are trying this ?

Comment: kitkat version but in lollipop 5.1.1 its working

Comment: where do you keep this file ?

Comment: check this link ;http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263002/how-to-get-file-name-from-uri

Comment: i will keep it in another activity as file name

Comment: am getting file name but it is in numeric but it has to be in characters

Comment: no i mean, where you have store this video.mp4 ?  is it in device storage ?

Comment: yes exactly it z der in device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("video/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 152);



    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == 152) {
                       final Uri uriVideoFromGalleryPath = data.getData();
                        final String selectedMediaPath =getPath(this, uriVideoFromGalleryPath);
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, selectedMediaPath , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    }}
```

// add this method outside onCreate().

```
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri The Uri to query.
 * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}


/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

Comment: am getting error at cannot reslove symbol context and data

Comment: context means your getApplicationContext() if using activity and if fragment then use getActivity();

Comment: data is from "" onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) ""

Comment: Intent  intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, null);
           // intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getVideoPathFromURI(getApplicationContext(),data));
            intent.setType("video/*");

            startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);

Comment: you have to use getVideoPathFromURI(getApplicationContext(),data)); in onActivityresult

Comment: Could you explain your solution to see what you tried to do ?

Comment: yes am getting but it is in numeric as i shown above

Comment: check now new ans which i had updted

Comment: selectedvideopath it is asking to i ntialize can i assign null value

Comment: please try to suggest some other thing i didn't get anything at all

Comment: Thak you very Much now its working fine in all devices

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

The path returned from intent is different in KitKat and lollipop. Could you please try this in KitKat.?

```
public String getVideoPathFromURI(Context context, Uri uri){

    String filePath = "";

    String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

    String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

    String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

   String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            column, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);

    if(cursor != null) {
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: Why ? Could you explain instead of just throwing code at his face, please.

Comment: calling method in onActivityResult but app is getting crashed

Comment: May be not much helpful to you but can u tell me what is the original filename is it video.mp4?

Comment: yes but not only that whatever we are selecting that video name has to get

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    String result;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        result = contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        result = cursor.getString(idx);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```