# How to extract file name from an Uri in C#?

Tags: c#, uri

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get file name from URI string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105593/get-file-name-from-uri-string-in-c-sharp)

How to extract file name from an Uri in C#?

for instance, I have a Uri

```
"http://audacity.googlecode.com/files/audacity-win-2.0.exe"
```

but how to extract the file name

```
"audacity-win-2.0.exe"
```

and save it as a string?

Thank you,

Jerry

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40361205/64334

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
Path.GetFileName(string path);
```

In your case

```
Path.GetFileName(new Uri("http://audacity.googlecode.com/files/audacity-win-2.0.exe").AbsolutePath);
```

Comment: it will give you nothing to filename.

Comment: This might be old but with this method for the example you will get empty string on the filename since IsFile is only true when you give a file:// type URI

Answer (score 9):

[`Path.GetFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename) can do it:

```cs
Uri u = new Uri("http://audacity.googlecode.com/files/audacity-win-2.0.exe");
Path.GetFileName(u.AbsolutePath);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. If you check uri.IsFile will give you false because is not a local file.

Answer (score 2):

E.g.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://audacity.googlecode.com/files/audacity-win-2.0.exe");
string Path.GetFileName(uri.AbsolutePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe to assume that a `URI` will always represent physical files therefore extracting file name from a `URI` is not always guaranteed.