# How do I edit this code to display the file name of the item being added to the list box instead of the file URL?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, media-player

I'm using VBE 2010

The Code is

```
Private Sub AddToPlaylistToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                                                 ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    Handles AddToPlaylistToolStripMenuItem.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Add(AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same concept as another post.  Check out the link below.  Basically, what you need is in Syste.IO.Path.GetFileName(string).

[Get file name from URI string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105593/get-file-name-from-uri-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: However, I don't know how to convert C# into Basic o_o

Comment: I am a hair rusty, but Dim filename as string = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL)

Comment: actually, that didn't work. :( it said something about not having a source e_o

Comment: actually, I just put it in the wrong place. But now, the filename doesn't act as a URL.

Comment: Let's take a step back.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm making a playlist option in my media player. I want it to add the file name to the playlist, but make said added file name act as the url for the file, so I can open the song from the file name.

Comment: So it sounds like you are trying to display just the filename to your users, but you still need to be able to open the file.  I would recommend something like what is detailed at this link.  That way your listbox can say one thing and your app can do another. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/b53718ba-046b-4754-931e-b18c2ac65113