# How To Download HTML File Name As A String?

Tags: c#, .net

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://rotter.net/scoopscache.html");
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1255);
//page = client.DownloadString("http://rotter.net/scoopscache.html");
page = client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, @"myhtml.html");
listsext.Ext(page);
```

If I'm using DownloadString, it will assign the html content to page.
I want the page to contain the file name, so I tried to use DownloadFileAsync but I'm getting error on this line:

```
Error   2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'
```

Comment: Well, that's because DownloadFileAsync returns void, not a string. And "Async" doesn't mean it's going to give you the filename, it means it's going to do the work asynchronously. What filename do you want it to contain? `scoopscache.html`?

Comment: Yes scoopscache.html or any other file name i will give but yes the downloaded file name.

Comment: You seem to know what file name it is without having to actually download it. Why can't you just pull it out of this line: `Uri uri = new Uri("http://rotter.net/scoopscache.html");`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation about the error:**

[WebClient.DownloadFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public void DownloadFileAsync(
    Uri address,
    string fileName
)
```

It doesn't return anything (void) and you are passing this to listsext! Ofcourse you will get an `Exception`:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'

**What you want to achieve: (my guess, not much information given)**

You want to have the filename, you don't need to download it.

```
Uri u = new Uri("http://rotter.net/scoopscache.html")
filename = Path.GetFileName(u.LocalPath);
```

See here: [Get file name from URI string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105593/get-file-name-from-uri-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: There is [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196(v=vs.110).aspx) to this method that only requires 2 parameters.

Comment: @mason: thanks, I missed the overload version of it. Updated the answer.