# How to save string content to a local file

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am developing an application which is showing web pages through a web browser control.

When I click the save button, the web page with images should be stored in local storage. It should be save in .html format.

I have the following code:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(txtURL.Text);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
string html = String.Empty;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
{
    html = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Now string html contains the webpage content. I need to save this into `D:\Cache\`

How do i save the html contents to disk?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code to write your HTML string to a file:

```
var path= @"D:\Cache\myfile.html";
File.WriteAllText(path, html);
```

Further refinement: Extract the filename from your (textual) URL.

**Update:**
See [Get file name from URI string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105593/get-file-name-from-uri-string-in-c-sharp) for details. The idea is:

```
var uri = new Uri(txtUrl.Text);

var filename = uri.IsFile 
  ? System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath)
  : "unknown-file.html";
```

Comment: hi jimileo.. its working fine. but how to save as with that particular website names..

Comment: string filename = txtURL.Text;
            var path= (@"D:\Cache\myfile.html");
            File.WriteAllText(path, html);
Now filename have the  name of webpage name.. so where I should include this filename to save as with the original name of website. I dnt want to split the hreflink.. here the path variable have "D:\Cache\myfile.html" whenever I save the webpage its saved into the folder with myfile.html.. I want to save with the txtURL.text value.. Please give solution.

Comment: `var path= @"D:\Cache\") + filename;`

Comment: My suggestion: Step (1) you accept this answer because it solves your initial question. (2) You state a new question for your new problem. This makes sense, because you will have to provide more information. How does your current code look like? How should your filename exactly look like? What is your expected and actual filename? E.g. just the filename part of the URL or - because you want to implement a cache - a url encode version of the URL and so on.

Comment: Hi JimiLoe.. I got output which is i want exactly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to write below code on save button

File.WriteAllText(path, browser.Document.Body.Parent.OuterHtml, Encoding.GetEncoding(browser.Document.Encoding));

Now the 'Body.parent' must save whole the page instead of just saving only  part.

check it.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built-in to the .NET Framework as far I know.

So my approach would be like below:

- Use `System.NET.HttpWebRequest` to get the main HTML document as a
  string or stream (easy). (Which you have done already)
- Load this into a [HTMLAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) document where you can now easily
  query the document to get lists of all image elements,    stylesheet
  links, etc.
- Then make a separate web request for each of these files and save
  them to a subdirectory.
- Finally update all relevent links in the main page to point to the
  items in the subdirectory.