# How to get real filename from a url in C#?

Tags: c#, url, filenames

I want to get the filename from a url for a download manager application. I know to get it using `Uri.AbsolutePath` or `Path.GetFileName` but these methods don't give good results for some urls.

For example, in this [link](https://cloclo9.cldmail.ru/KRKzZdHVjhmERj6XoUR/G/EBvc/zjESdHoqm?key=035db62f2375981abf05c615955812a72d5f2701) the realname is *WinRAR 5.40 Final TR.zip*, but the `Path.GetFileName` gives it as *zjESdHoqm?key=035db62f2375981abf05c615955812a72d5f2701* which is a strange name.

There is also no redirection for this link. It contains the file directly. So I want to ask, Is there an exact way to get the correct filename in C#?

**UPDATE:** I have figured out the link expires. Sorry for that. But I couldn't any other URL to explain my problem.

If you want to test my problem, you can renew the url from this [page](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/EBvc/zjESdHoqm).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105593/get-file-name-from-uri-string-in-c-sharp  ?

Comment: I tried the method in your link, but it gives `zjESdHoqm` at this time. So it is not what I want.

Comment: Where are these files located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a good solution for it by myself.

```
public static string getFileName(string url)
{
   HttpWebRequest req = RequestSender.SendRequest(url);
   HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
   string header_contentDisposition = resp.Headers["content-disposition"];
   string escaped_filename = new ContentDisposition(header_contentDisposition).FileName;

   return Uri.UnescapeDataString(escaped_filename);
}
```

So finally, the filename is correct. Thanks everyone tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your link is broken (404), but you might look at this: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath.aspx

Request.Url.AbsolutePath

> The AbsolutePath property contains the path information that the
>   server uses to resolve requests for information

Comment: The link is expired, it seems. Sorry for that. The url is taken from https://cloud.mail.ru/public/EBvc/zjESdHoqm and it can be refreshed from that address.