# how to get filename from URL without downloading file c#

Tags: c#, url, filenames

this is my code

```
Uri uri = new Uri(this.Url);
var data = client.DownloadData(uri);
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Disposition"]))
{
    FileName = client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Disposition"].Substring(client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Disposition"].IndexOf("filename=") + 10).Replace("\"", "");
}
```

how to get the file name without download the file, I mean without using `client.DownloadData`??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get file name from URI string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105593/get-file-name-from-uri-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebClient will not support it but with HttpWebRequest you can either try to be nice and send a HEAD request if the server supports it or if it doesn't  send a normal GET request and just don't download the data:

The HEAD request:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "HEAD";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
string disposition = response.Headers["Content-Disposition"];
string filename = disposition.Substring(disposition.IndexOf("filename=") + 10).Replace("\"", "");
response.close();
```

If the server doesn't support HEAD, send a normal GET request:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
string disposition = response.Headers["Content-Disposition"];
string filename = disposition.Substring(disposition.IndexOf("filename=") + 9).Replace("\"", "");
response.close();
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this is just save my 8 hours of searching before I post this, thanks sir, thank you so much.

Comment: Should be `disposition.IndexOf("filename=") + 9` instead of `disposition.IndexOf("filename=") + 10` to prevent possibly cutting off the first character of the file name.