# Selenium c# https://baseurl/config/dteg/vt2k/standard/vt2k-dev-standard.txt I want to extract vt2k-dev-standard.txt

Tags: c#, web, url, selenium-webdriver

when I press an icon in my application, it automatically generates a file and opens its contents in the url in a new tab or current tab whichever way you look at it

```
https://BASEURL/config/dteg/vt2k/standard/vt2k-dev-standard.txt
```

I want to read in the full url and extract the last filename and store it in a string.  Can you please help me?

Thank you

I haven't tried anything yet.  Anything I have tried either gets the previous url in old tab or just simply gets the base url.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get file name from URI string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105593/get-file-name-from-uri-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Found out what I was looking for.  For everyone who don't know here is the code:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("https://BASEURL/config/dteg/vt2k/standard/vt2k-dev-standard.txt");
string lastSegment = uri.Segments.Last();
```