# Get file name without extension from URL

Tags: c#, url

I have the following URL:

```
www.mysite.com/type/text.gif
www.mysite.com/type/video.gif
www.mysite.com/gettype.php?giveme=text.gif
www.mysite.com/gettype.php?giveme=video.gif
```

I have the following code to extract the file name from url:

```
var type = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("www.mysite.com/type/text.gif"); // text
type = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("www.mysite.com/type/video.gif"); // video
type = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("www.mysite.com/gettype.php?giveme=text.gif"); // gettype.php?giveme=text
type = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("www.mysite.com/gettype.php?giveme=video.gif"); // gettype.php?giveme=video
```

On the first two links I got the expected result - the file name but on the last two results I don't get the expected result, How can I got the file name from any url?

Comment: `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` is for *files*, not URLs. I suggest you use the `System.Net.Uri` class to get the path from the URL, *then* you can call `GetFileNameWithoutExtension` based on just the path part.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get file name from URI string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105593/get-file-name-from-uri-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: With the use of ```System.Net.Uri``` you easily get "gettype.php" as filename. But to get "text.gif" you have to split the ```Query```.